# Php hash return type: Not string(64)?

Tags: php, hash

I am performing a hash on various data. On most data, after I get the result of the hash, I can do a var_dump of the hash, and it will print:

```
> string(64) "<hash goes here>"
```

However, for one of the data that I am hashing, the result prints the hash, with no "string(64)" preceding it, and no quotes around it.

```
> <hash goes here>
```

What would be the cause of this? Is it possibly due to the size of the data?

Code example, of what I should see:

```
$string= "hello";
$hash = hash( 'sha512', $string, true );
var_dump($hash);
```

This should print:

```
string(64) "<hash value of 'hello'>"
```

In my case, replace "hello" with the contents of a long php file. For some reason the var_dump is not printing the value in quotes with "string(64)" in front of it.

Comment: Can you show the code that reproduces this?

Comment: what is the hash which doesn't have string(64) in front of it?

Comment: It's too long to type out, but it's a php file.

Comment: are you trimming the hash?

Comment: No, I am doing just as the code example shows. For most files it will print with string(64) in front of the result. But for one of my files it doesn't.

Comment: What if you view the source of the page? Do you see the `string( 64)` now?

Comment: are you sure you're using var_dump in the "doesn't" case? print_r will also dump arbitrary contents but doesn't include the type/size information.

Comment: It's a for-loop that does the exact same thing to all of the files, so I'm certain that it has something to do with that file. Is there anything like, data size, the input type, or something else that may affect the result of the hash function?

Comment: @nickb What do you mean, view the source? I have a bunch of php files put into string form, and then hashed.

Comment: I assume you're viewing the output of this script in a browser. If not, then disregard my comment. However, if you are, try to view the page source in your browser.

Comment: Let's put it this way: it's **impossible** if you use `var_dump`. That prefix and the quotes have nothing to do with the value itself, it's the format `var_dump` uses to output strings. Please provide valid actual code that demonstrates what you see.

Comment: @nickb I'm viewing it in the command line. No problem.

Comment: @deceze What is impossible? I've updated my example.

Comment: Show us the result of `var_dump(bin2hex($theHash))` of that special hash which supposedly breaks `var_dump`.

Comment: It starts with 9a, which I looked up and it seems to be a control code for SCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using third parameter set to *true* in hash function, so your output is in **binary** format, that is not suitable to be viewed in standard output. Previous hash may contain some control chars that suppresses part of next output. Binary data should be viewed in hex form (third parameter set to *false*) or saved to file and browsed by hex editor.

Comment: Thanks, that must be it. Just curious, if I had the hex, would there be a way to confirm that this is the case? IE. Is there something like an ascii chart for control chars

Comment: In hex my hash started with 9a, which I found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes

Comment: If you start using hex, you should get `string(128)` before every hash. Every two characters bellow *0x20* (32 in decimal) are control characters.